# Sorting by Date then Location

Tags: javascript, function, datetime

I have a function that I use to sort events by Date :

```
function SortByDateAsc() {

    return function (a,b) {

        var aDate = new Date(new Date(a['Month'] +" "+ a['Day']+ " "+ a['Year']));
        var bDate = new Date(new Date(b['Month'] +" "+ b['Day']+ " "+ b['Year']));

        return (aDate < bDate) ? -1 : (aDate > bDate) ? 1 : 0;

    }
}
```

If I wanted to sort by date then by location e.g I have two results for the same date but they are in two different locations.How would I add the locations to be sorted alphabetically?

So my end results should be the dates plus the location in alphabetical order??

Answer (score 3):

Add a similar check for the location before returning `0`. Also, there is a far less-convoluted way to create dates.

```
function SortByDateAsc() {
  return function (a,b) {
    // the month-1 is because Date months are 0-indexed, which
    // might not be necessary if your months are already 0-indexes
    var aDate = new Date(a.Year, a.Month-1, a.Day).getTime();
    var bDate = new Date(b.Year, b.Month-1, b.Day).getTime();

    return (aDate < bDate) ? -1 : (aDate > bDate) ? 1 : someLocationComparator(a,b);
  }
}
```

Have a good read over [the `Date` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 1):

The return value will tell the system what order do you want.

If you want to sort two same-date events just do not return 0 on the sort function:

```
function SortByDateAsc() {
    return function (a,b) {

        var aDate = new Date(new Date(a['Month'] +" "+ a['Day']+ " "+ a['Year']));
        var bDate = new Date(new Date(b['Month'] +" "+ b['Day']+ " "+ b['Year']));

        var diff = aDate - bDate;
        if (diff !== 0)
            return diff;

        return (a.location < b.location) ? -1 : (a.location > b.location) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```